# Not able to send mail using javamail

Tags: java, jsp, exception, sendmail

I am trying to send mail through java api, i had copied activation.jar and mail.jar in web-inf/lib which had resolved all problems but still i am getting below set of exceptions, and not able to run the program, please have a look

```
**JSP CODE**

   <html>
   <head>
   <title>JSP JavaMail Example </title>
   </head>
   <body>
   <%@ page import="java.util.*" %>
   <%@ page import="javax.mail.*" %>
   <%@ page import="javax.mail.internet.*" %>
   <%@ page import="javax.activation.*" %>
   <%
   String host = "mail.google.com";
   String to = request.getParameter("smzk07@gmail.com");
   String from = request.getParameter("heady.syed@gmail.com");
   String subject = request.getParameter("Create test description");
   String messageText = request.getParameter("hello sir");
   boolean sessionDebug = false;
// Create some properties and get the default Session.
   Properties props = System.getProperties();
   props.put("mail.host", host);
   props.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
   Session mailSession = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);

// Set debug on the Session
// Passing false will not echo debug info, and passing True will.

   mailSession.setDebug(sessionDebug);

// Instantiate a new MimeMessage and fill it with the 
// required information.

   Message msg = new MimeMessage(mailSession);
   msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
   InternetAddress[] address = {new InternetAddress(to)};
   msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, address);
   msg.setSubject(subject);
   msg.setSentDate(new Date());
   msg.setText(messageText);

// Hand the message to the default transport service
// for delivery.

   Transport.send(msg);
   out.println("Mail was sent to " + to);
   out.println(" from " + from);
                out.println(" using host " + host + ".");
   %>
  </table>
  </body>
  </html>
```

**exception**

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:549)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:470)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
```

**root cause**

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress.parse(InternetAddress.java:673)
    javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress.parse(InternetAddress.java:633)
    javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress.<init>(InternetAddress.java:111)
    org.apache.jsp.send_0020mail_jsp._jspService(send_0020mail_jsp.java:97)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
```

I am a newbie to JSP and java technologies, I will really appreciate your help.

Comment: Please show the code you are using and specific values that are causing problems.

Comment: could you please post your jsp file here?

Comment: We need to see your code to be sure, but it sure looks from your trace like you have not assigned a value to an `InternetAddress` object that's needed (perhaps the mail server URL?)

Answer (score 2):

Look at these two lines:

```
String to = request.getParameter("smzk07@gmail.com");
String from = request.getParameter("heady.syed@gmail.com");
```

you are stating, that you want to get the parameters named like email-addresses, instead, you probably want to say `String from="smzk07@gmail.com";`, try that instead.

Comment: +1 This is the cause of the NPE. There is no request parameter named `smzk07@gmail.com`, so this is returning `null` for both `to` and `from`. You pass these values (`null`) to javaMail which then throws NPE.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you want to be using request.getParameter with the parameters you are using?  Based on the code you posted, your request would look something like:

```
bob.com/mail?smzk07@gmail.com=someone@bob.com
```

(obviously with the proper escape codes)

The reason you are getting a null pointer exception is that the parameter names you are requesting are not set(requesting a parameter that doesn't exist will give you a null result)

You are probably trying to do something like:

```
bob.com/mail?from=smzk07@gmail.com&to=....
```

in which case you would need to use:

request.getParameter("from");
request.getParameter("to");

etc.